# Making sure a date is always in UK format

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I make sure a date in always in UK format, when the date may or may not be in UK format

For instance, if I pass a date such as

```
string Date = "10/1/2014 12:00:00 AM";
```

which is in american format

I can use something like

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTime result2 = Convert.ToDateTime(usDate, usDtfi);
```

to convert that back to a UK date

but if I pass in a Uk date like `1/10/2014 12:00:00 AM`, then its obviously converted to American

How can I make sure the date that I get passed always ends up in UK format when I don't know the initial locale

I need to set the date to uk format regardless, can anyone help

Thanks

Comment: Is the input always a string?

Comment: is this date read from DB/xml etc or input by user?

Comment: Hi, the date comes from the database (sql server) it is a column returned on a sproc. It seems this one customer has set there sql up with an american locale. Its not possible for them to change this on there database server

Comment: If I pass you '10/1/2014' and '1/10/2014' how would you know which one is the UK format versus the US format?  The dates could be Jan 1st or Oct 1st.

Comment: Have the proc changed to return a native date/time from the database instead of a string. It's the only way.

Comment: How are you displaying the date? what is the culture on the c# application set to? formatting of a date should be an application issue not a server issue.

Comment: If your DB always returns the date/time in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, for example, your problems are gone. Or likely to be.

Comment: If the column holfing the date a string (varchar etc) or a Date/DateTime type?

Comment: If you can describe precisely in words how you determine what the source locale is then we can help you realise this in code. If you don't know what the initial locale is though then I don't see how you can decide whether something needs to be done or not. Also it might be worth clarifying how the date is stored in the database. It sounds like it is being returned as a string but is it being stored as one or is the procedure making it one?

Comment: *"How can I make sure the date that I get passed always ends up in UK format when I don't know the initial locale"* If you don't know the locale, you cannot correctly parse it in all cases. Simple as that.